# JSONDecodeError at / Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when try to return response in a django rest_framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to python `rest_framework`. I am trying to create a `django` website with two `App`s.
The *first App* has an **HTML form** which gets a city name from the user and then sends a request to **the API in the second App**, calls `WeatherApp`. In the `WeatherApp` I read data from database and serialize it but when trying to `return response`, I get this error:

> JSONDecodeError at /
> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

This is the first App `views`:

```
def index(request):
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']

        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/city/{}"
        city_weather = requests.get(url.format(name)).json()
```

And this is the `WeatherApp` `views`:

```
def myfunc(self, cityname):
    query = City.objects.filter(name = cityname)[0]
    serializer = CitySerializer(query)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and share the solution for anyone with a similar problem:

The problem was in the `return` in `WeatherApp` `views`.
It should be like this:

```
return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

and the `JsonResponse` should import like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```